# Reputation for Edits

Tags: support, reputation

When do you stop receiving reputation for editing posts?  I haven't come anywhere near the +1000 rep cap, but I appear to not get any reputation for edits (not that I do that many).  I read this in the FAQ:

> The other way to gain reputation is by suggesting edits to existing
>   posts as a new registered user. Each edit will be peer reviewed, and
>   if it is accepted, you will earn +2 reputation. You can only earn a
>   maximum of +1000 total reputation through suggested edits, however.

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation

I'm assuming "new registered user" has something to do with it, but that is not clear what it means; that phrase is vague.  I don't have that much rep here to qualify for much other than a newer user.

For an edit example:

I modified this [post](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/9853/free-alternative-to-bugzilla), received an excavator badge, but no rep for the edit.  Maybe I'm not supposed to get rep for that and I just don't know the rules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have more than 2,000 reputation so you are trusted to make edits on your own now.

Because there's no review there's no +2 for suggesting a good edit.

You can still get +2 for suggesting tag wiki edits (up to the cap of 1,000 points of course)